# iOS - Using custom framework causing 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' in simulator only

Tags: ios, crash, frameworks, simulator

I am using the [ClippingBezier](https://github.com/adamwulf/ClippingBezier) framework. I compiled the framework using the steps provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34643933/revisions) and added it to my project. When the project is run on actual devices, namely iPhones and iPads, it works perfectly. However, in the simulator, the app crashed with the error `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBezierPath findIntersectionsWithClosedPath:andBeginsInside:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` where the method mentioned in the error is found in the framework.

Any help to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinks you are building the framework without simulator architecture, you should choose simulator when build the framework, and navigate to `Release/iphonesimulator` and use that framework if you want to test your framework in simulator, the file in `release/iphoneos` is only for use in device target.

Create aggregate target with run script can help create fat framework (include both device and simulator archs) but app with this framework wont make it to AppStore. Sample script can be found in [here](https://gist.github.com/sundeepgupta/3ad9c6106e2cd9f51c68cf9f475191fa).

To create framework for simulator, compile the framework while targeting any simulator in device target.

Comment: How does one specify simulator architecture?  My`Valid Architectures` currently contains `arm64 armv7 armv7s`.

Comment: Just compile your framework while choosing your device target as any simulator, then check the folder for the file

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this as answer. By mistake, I clicked on downvote. If you could make some edit on your original answer, I will be able to upvote again.

Comment: Perfect Answer!